# Calculating the size of attributed text with custom font in iOS

Tags: ios7, nsattributedstring, uifont, rect

I want to calculate the drawing rect for my attributed text which is assigned to a label so that label frame can be changed based on the size.

The attributed text assigned to label have custom font and paragraph info.

I used boundingRectWithSize API to calculate but this API is not working as expected. How this can be done in iOS?

Adding the code for understanding

```
self.textLabel.attributedText = [Utilities attributedStringFromText:[dbObject valueForKey:@"content"]];

//change the frame of the label according to content
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(320,9999);

CGSize textSize= [self.textLabel.attributedText boundingRectWithSize:maximumSize
                                                             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                             context:nil].size;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working as expected?"

Comment: @RobNapier: The height is appears less and my text is getting truncated.

Comment: And your layout code works correctly with non-custom fonts? How many points is it off by (always the same number of points)? It is truncated both vertically and horizontally? It has the same problems without `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin`? Why have you chosen to use `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin`? What have you tried already?

Comment: I didn't try with non custom code. I believe it is noting to do with font. If I set simply text attribute of the label and not attribute text then it works.

Answer (score 2):

If `textLabel` uses a single font, you can supply it in the attributes *(Using `.UsesFontLeading` or `NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading` option)*.

## Swift

```
let size:CGSize = self.textLabel.attributedText.string.boundingRectWithSize(
    CGSizeMake(self.textLabel.bounds.width, CGFloat.max),
    options: (.UsesLineFragmentOrigin | .UsesFontLeading),
    attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : font],
    context: nil).size
```

Putting it all together (get the font from the attributed text) in **Swift**:

```
self.textLabel.attributedText.enumerateAttribute(
    NSFontAttributeName,
    inRange: NSMakeRange(0, self.textLabel.attributedText.length),
    options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions(0)) {
        (value:AnyObject!, range:NSRange, stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        stop.initialize(true)
        if let font:UIFont = value as? UIFont {
            let size:CGSize = self.textLabel.attributedText.string.boundingRectWithSize(
                CGSizeMake(self.textLabel.bounds.width, CGFloat.max),
                options: (.UsesLineFragmentOrigin | .UsesFontLeading),
                attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : font],
                context: nil).size
            self.textHeight.constant = size.height // Use height
        }
}
```

## Obj-C

```
CGSize size = [self.textLabel.attributedText.string
            boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.textLabel.bounds.size.width,
                                            CGFLOAT_MAX)
            options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin |
                     NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
            attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}
            context:nil].size;
```

Putting it all together (get the font from the attributed text) in **Obj-C**:

```
[self.textLabel.attributedText
 enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
 inRange:(NSRange){0, self.textLabel.attributedText.length}
 options:(NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions)0
 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
     *stop = YES;
     if( [value isKindOfClass:[UIFont class]]) {
         UIFont * font = (UIFont*)value;
         CGSize size = [self.textLabel.attributedText.string
                        boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.textLabel.bounds.size.width,
                                                        CGFLOAT_MAX)
                        options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin |
                                 NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}
                        context:nil].size;
         self.textHeight.constant = size.height; // USe height
     }
 }];
```

Comment: if a string contains emoji, it might gives you wrong height tho.

Comment: Attributed text may contain paragraphs, different fonts so this won't calculate size correctly. It's good only for simple cases.